# using jmx monitor kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I am using jmx to monitoring kafka topic.

```
val url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://broker1:9393/jmxrmi");

 val jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
 val mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
 val messageCountObj = new ObjectName("kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=mytopic");
 val messagesInPerSec = mbsc.getAttribute(messageCountObj,"MeanRate")
```

using this code I can get the MeanRate of "mytopic" on broker1.
but I have 10 brokers,how can I get the "mytopic"'s MeanRate from all my brokers?

I have try "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://broker1:9393,broker2:9393,broker3:9393/jmxrmi"

got an error :(

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if it were that simple ;)

There's no way to do this as you outlined. You will need to make a seperate connection to each broker.

One possible solution would be to use [MBeanServer Federation](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/federating_mbeanservers_with_opendmk) which would register proxies for each of your brokers in one MBeanServer, so if you did this on **broker1**, you could connect to `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://broker1:9393/jmxrmi` and query the stats for all your brokers in one go, but you would need to query 10 different ObjectNames, query the value for each and then compute the MeanRate yourself. [Java] Pseudo code:

```
ObjectName wildcard = new ObjectName("*:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=mytopic");
double totalRate = 0d;
int respondingBrokers = 0;
for(ObjectName on : mbsc.queryNames(wildcard, null)) {
   totalRate += (Double)mbsc.getAttribute(messageCountObj,"MeanRate");
   respondingBrokers++;
}
// Average rate of mean rates: totalRate/respondingBrokers
```

Note: no exception handling, and I am assuming the rate type is a Double.

You could also create and register a custom MBean that computed the aggregate mean on the federated broker.

If you are maven oriented, you can build the OpenDMK from [here](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK).